# Looping over a generator

Tags: python, for-loop, generator, python-3.7

I want to loop over a generator and yield the outputs of the generator until StopIteration.

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> 
>>> def funct_one(list, number):
...     for item in list:
...         if item > number:
...             yield item
... 
>>> funct_one(list,0).__next__()
1
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def another_funct():
...     number = 0
...     while funct_one(list, number).__next__() != StopIteration:
...         yield funct_one(list, number).__next__()
...         number += 1
...     if funct_one(list, number).__next__() == StopIteration:
...         break
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 7
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
>>> for item in another_funct():
...     print(item)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in another_funct
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

How do I only print the items, without getting the error message?

Comment: Why can't you just use a `for` loop?

Comment: You're actually creating many different generators and only taking the first value from each.  That's a very unusual pattern, and probably means your design is flawed.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It's a study example for me to study StopIteration, so the quality of the first for loop is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I used `except StopIteration` line:

```
def another_funct():
    number = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield funct_one(list, number).__next__()
            number += 1
        except StopIteration:
            break

for item in another_funct():
    print(item)
```